# При нажатии кнопки очищать textbox(searchTXT) с событием TextChanged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Мне нужно осуществить поиск в textbox(searchTXT) с событием TextChanged, для теста я вывожу MessageBox с текстом "Hello". Когда ввожу символы все работает нормально, MessageBox выводиться корректно, но когда я нажимаю кнопку очистки, поле очищается и выводится MessageBox. Как мне сделать чтобы при очистки не выводился MessageBox?

Вот фрагмент события textbox:

```
private void toolStripTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");

        }
```

Фрагмент кнопки:

```
private void очиститиПолеПошукуToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchTXT.Clear();
        }
```